# Laravel 5.8 JWT-token with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, jwt, rest

i'm using jwt with driver table for authentication when i try to login it gives me invalid credentials error 400 please does anyone face this type of errors.i'm using laravel 5.8 version

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? What does your request that gets rejected with 400 contain? What are the columns of your "driver" table? Are you using a package? How are you actually validating the JWT token? Etc.

Comment: the register works fine but when i try to login with email and password it won't work .i'm using bmatovu/multi-auth package

Comment: You need to provide details. No one can help you with the information currently provided.

Comment: sorry my english is not good

Comment: That is ok :) As I said before, I think the most helpful thing would be to show us dd() of the request that returns 400.

Comment: if (! $token = guard()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
             return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }   return $this->createNewToken($token);

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the package you are using. I have looked over the basic docs but don't have the time to invest here. Please add dd($request); to your question so someone with knowledge can help you.